# Regex question ^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}$

Tags: java, regex

The above regular expression (in Java) matches a string of alpha numeric characters of length between 5 and 10.

How can I modify the above regular expression to  match with the above requirements as well as matching with an empty string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make it optional (match exactly one or zero times)

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10})?$
```

Comment: Thanks, your idea works and the explanation easy to understand.

Comment: No prob, btw. the ? quantifier is just a shortcut for {0,1}

Answer (score 4):

`^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10}|)$`

Comment: You see the pipe "|" nearly at the end of the regex? It's like an OR operator, in this case ` [a-zA-Z0-9]{5,10} ` OR "" :)